# Poisson Compound Process

Tags: probability

$N(t)$ is a Poisson process with parameter  $\lambda> 0$, and $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with a common mean and positive variance. Let
$$L(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}X_i.$$
Find $E[L(t)|N(t) = n]$.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Please learn LaTeX, or rather, its small subset allowing to post maths here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$
{\rm E}[L(t)\mid N(t)=n]={\rm E}[L(t)\mathbf{1}_{\{N(t)=n\}}]/P(N(t)=n),
$$
where $1_A$ denotes the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$.